# SQL functions (String Selection)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I/P : P-2120-001-A10 I need O/p As P-2120 using SQL Server Functions.
 this is the given string 'P-2120-001-A10' and i need to select data from given string left of the second '-' symbol i.e 'P-2120' its should select dynamically

Comment: That is not clear. What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it isn't clear what you are asking for this will transform `I/P : P-2120-001-A10` into `O/p As P-2120`

```
with sample as (
    select 'I/P : P-2120-001-A10' as astring
    )

select
    substring(astring,7,6)             AS guess1
  , 'O/p As ' + substring(astring,7,6) AS guess2
from sample
```

Answer (score 0):

After your Question edit, you could use `SUBSTRING` & `CHARINDEX` Function to read the data from string left of the second '-' symbol Dynamically.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(<I/P>, 1, CHARINDEX('-', <I/P>)-1)+'-'+SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(<I/P>, CHARINDEX('-', <I/P>)+1, LEN(<I/P>)), 1, CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(<I/P>, CHARINDEX('-', <I/P>)+1, LEN(<I/P>)))-1);
```

**Output :**

```
P-2120
```